# How to find the name of plugins so you can install them via WordPress CLI?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to install this plugin via the WordPress CLI:

https://wpmailsmtp.com/docs/a-complete-guide-to-wp-mail-smtp-mailers/

So I'm trying to do something like:

```
 "wp plugin install [nameofplugin] --activate"
```

But I can't seem to find any documentation explaining how to find the name.  I must have been looking at this too long.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress CLI supports multiple sources for installing plugins, but for since the [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)  plugin you're referencing is listed on WordPress.org, you can determine what to use based on its URL:

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

WP CLI expects final segment of the URL for any plugins hosted on WordPress.org, so you can do the following:

```
wp plugin install wp-mail-smtp --activate
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Alternatively, if a plugin is not available on WordPress.org, you can also use a URL for a ZIP file:

```
wp plugin install https://example.com/plugin.zip
```

Full examples are available in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/install/).